# Could I run a some http server on UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

For my app, I need to build a http server in order to serve static files and dynamic data (API). I have tried basic samples and libraries as EmbedIO that I use on other apps on Xamarin Forms. But on Windows 10 UWP I haven’t got it works. App never answer request of external browser. Do you know if I can build a http server on UWP app? If it is possible, how should I build it?
Thank you

Comment: With .NET Standard 2.0 support in UWP, you should be able to find classes such as `HttpListener`.

Comment: You can use tcp listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Tcp Listener to do it.

Here is a library that uses http server on UWP, https://github.com/PeterWaher/IoTGateway/tree/master/Networking/Waher.Networking.HTTP.UWP

And you can find Firefly's app, Http server app, on [Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NT5T97KHPQG) that uses this library.

And you can also use the socket to do it see [Simple HTTP Server in C# - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C)

Comment: The thing you can't do is run on port 80.

Comment: You should read the licence about Waher.Networking. It's working great but it require commercial licence (even if it's on Github !)